# sed: replace range with file content

Tags: sed

How can I replace a range with the content of a file, *once*? Using the sed script

```
/<start>/,/<end>/{
  d
  r <filename>
}
```

reads the file into every line. I doesn't need to be done with `sed`, of course, but I have the feeling that there isn't much missing.

Comment: Yup that works, thanks. I actually found `/<start>/r ..` to work too.

Comment: Please, someone answer to this ? Not working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange the commands to get the desired output:

```
    /<start>/,/<end>/{
      /<end>/r <filename>
      d
    }
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that you can add patterns inside `{...}`.